# Draw camera axis on image

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I have some images and I want to draw the camera axis (pose) on them.
For each image I know the camera rotation matrix, the translation vector and the camera intrinsics matrix.

[I took this tutorial as an example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html)
but I did not calibrate the camera with opencv and the chessboard, I get the camera calibration from another software.
Using projectPoints gives me strange results.

This is more or less what I do

```
# Initialize axis
axis = np.float32([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,-1]]).reshape(-1,3)

# Initialize camera matrix, shared between all images
C = np.float32([[2696.178, 0, 1633.029], [0, 2696.178, 910.477], [0, 0, 1]])

for img in os.listdir(folder):

    # ... get R and T from the calibration file... 

    rvec, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R)

    imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvec, T, C, np.float32([0, 0, 0, 0]))

    # ... draw axis on image ...
```

If I draw the axis from the image center, they seems in a completely random position between different images

[image]

Here I post the data I'm using for the above images

```
# Camera intrinsics matrix
# [[fx 0  cx]
#  [0  fy cy]
#  [0  0  1]]
C = [[2.696178e+03 0.000000e+00 1.633029e+03]
 [0.000000e+00 2.696178e+03 9.104770e+02]
 [0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00]]

# Image 0
R = [[ 0.86863263  0.37673212 -0.32179227]
 [-0.44287505  0.88156808 -0.16339952]
 [ 0.22212395  0.28444792  0.93260406]]
T = [-0.21416583 -0.2571567   0.16956859]


# Image 1
R = [[ 0.90208208  0.32308862 -0.28611477]
 [-0.29805909  0.94587646  0.1283686 ]
 [ 0.31210366 -0.03051991  0.94955771]]
T = [-2.40984019e-01  8.82576072e-05  4.76871846e-02]


# Image 2
R = [[ 0.96358973  0.20786754 -0.16818418]
 [-0.19664438  0.97712118  0.0810259 ]
 [ 0.18117898 -0.04500325  0.98241991]]
T = [-0.13990368  0.00922085  0.03539171]


# Image 3
R = [[ 0.99998207  0.00499065 -0.00330968]
 [-0.00499566  0.99998639 -0.00150651]
 [ 0.00330212  0.00152301  0.99999339]]
T = [0.00201909 0.00020396 0.01447096]
```

The images are 3264x1840. The results given the points (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0) are:

```
# Image 0
(6137.9883, -3908.1243)
(2598.4294, 4618.5454)
(1252.732, 1241.767)
(-1772.2549,  -3178.3713)

# Image 1
(6587.124, -1322.4381)
(14527.832, 149477.4)
(1498.1089, 1293.9762)
(-11991.927, 915.467)

# Image 2
(11887.4375, -1422.836)
(-17431.814, -275772.7)
(1552.5148, 1114.9052)
(-9024.983, 1612.931)

# Image 3
(153636.7, 183.5757)
(2814.6936, 169517.17)
(1618.4507, 905.79755)
(2009.2186, 948.4782)
```

Comment: Did you project the axes to the image plane?

Comment: how big are your images (in px)? 3266x1820 ? can you show the result of your projected points? can you also project the origin? point [0,0,0].

Comment: I'm confused here. You say you want to draw the camera axis, but you are projecting the unit axes given in the object/world coordinate frame, into the image given its extrinsic parameters. Given that interpretation, your plots look mostly correct, except for possibly a flipped "green" axis in one image. Plotting a camera pose in the image it refers to is pointless, since it will always look the same (e.g. the z-axis is always pointing straight out from the image, and is thus a dot).

Comment: Mmh yes, you are right, in the opencv tutorial they estimate the pose of an object (chessboard) in the image, not the camera axis.